# UITableViewCell StackView Hidden Elements

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a `TableViewCell` that has 2 `StackViews`. One of the `StackViews` has 3 components and one of which is hidden. By pressing on a button, I want the hidden `UIImageView` to appear. While my code does this, it does not format it correctly as the height of the `TableViewCell` does not change, as I would like it to. I have tried calls to `sizeToFit()`, but I am starting to realize that this will not affect the height of a cell. When the cell leaves the view and comes back, it draws correctly. How can I update the height of the cell when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

After writing out this question, I started to realize that the problem was from the cell's height. After doing a little bit more research I found out that this can be achieved with the

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

I had to create a delegate and add a delegate method to reference back to the `ViewController`.

Hope this helps someone else!